# How do I get the random question to not appear again?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I can't seem to fix how to get my questions to not appear again after they have been shown once...
Does anyone have any idea?

```
import random
from turtle import *
import time

def reset(x, y):
    print("Körs")
    clearscreen()

    # Här gör man det enklare för sig själv genom att kategorisera turtles.
    #Turtle()

    # Här väljer man vilken fart turtles skall ha när dom ritar
    speed(10)

    # här göms alla turtles
    hideturtle()

    # Här skriver man vad programmet heter och vilken färg bakgrunden har.
    title('Albins ofungerade spel')
    Screen().bgcolor("orange")

    quest = ('Courier', 15, 'italic')
    main = ('Courier', 25, 'italic')

    frågor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    computer_action = random.choice(frågor)

    # här ritas alla olika boxar och sidor
    l = 300
    w = 75

    penup()
    goto(-150, 100)
    pendown()

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    penup()
    goto(-150, 0)
    pendown()

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    penup()
    goto(-150, -100)
    pendown()

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    forward(l)
    left(90)

    forward(w)
    left(90)

    penup()
    goto(-150, -200)
    pendown()

    forward(l)  # Forward turtle by l units
    left(90)  # Turn turtle by 90 degree

    forward(w)  # Forward turtle by w units
    left(90)  # Turn turtle by 90 degree

    forward(l)  # Forward turtle by l units
    left(90)  # Turn turtle by 90 degree

    forward(w)  # Forward turtle by w units
    left(90)  # Turn turtle by 90 degree

    def good():
        penup()
        setposition(0, -280)
        pendown()
        write("Rätt val! Tryck på skärmen för ny fråga", font=main, align='center')
        onscreenclick(reset)


    def bad():
        penup()
        setposition(0, -280)
        pendown()
        write("Fel val! Tryck på skärmen för ny fråga", font=main, align='center')
        onscreenclick(reset)



    if computer_action == 1:


        penup()
        setposition(0, 130)
        pendown()
        write("A. Danmark", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 30)
        pendown()
        write("B. Sverige", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -70)
        pendown()
        write("C. Finland", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -170)
        pendown()
        write("D. Norge", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 250)
        pendown()
        write("Vad heter det största landet i Norden?", font=main, align='center')

        onkeypress(good, 'b')
        onkeypress(bad, 'd')
        onkeypress(bad, 'c')
        onkeypress(bad, 'a')
        listen()



    elif computer_action == 2:

        penup()
        setposition(0, 130)
        pendown()
        write("A. Java", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 30)
        pendown()
        write("B. C++", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -70)
        pendown()
        write("C. Python", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -170)
        pendown()
        write("D. LUA", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 250)
        pendown()
        write("Vad är William och Svens favorit språk?", font=main, align='center')

        onkeypress(good, 'd')
        onkeypress(bad, 'a')
        onkeypress(bad, 'c')
        onkeypress(bad, 'b')
        listen()

    elif computer_action == 3:

        penup()
        setposition(0, 130)
        pendown()
        write("A. Fredrik Reignfeldt", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 30)
        pendown()
        write("B. Magdalenda Andersson", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -70)
        pendown()
        write("C. Sven Blomqvist", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -170)
        pendown()
        write("D. Martin Nilsson", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 250)
        pendown()
        write("Vad heter Sveriges statsminister?", font=main, align='center')

        onkeypress(good, 'b')
        onkeypress(bad, 'a')
        onkeypress(bad, 'c')
        onkeypress(bad, 'd')
        listen()

    elif computer_action == 4:

        penup()
        setposition(0, 130)
        pendown()
        write("A. Joe Biden", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 30)
        pendown()
        write("B. Bill Clinton", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -70)
        pendown()
        write("C. Donald Trump", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -170)
        pendown()
        write("D. Albin Winqvist", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 250)
        pendown()
        write("Vad heter USA's president?", font=main, align='center')

        onkeypress(good, 'a')
        onkeypress(bad, 'd')
        onkeypress(bad, 'c')
        onkeypress(bad, 'b')
        listen()

    elif computer_action == 5:

        penup()
        setposition(0, 130)
        pendown()
        write("A. Borgarskolan", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 30)
        pendown()
        write("B. Procivitas", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -70)
        pendown()
        write("C. Bernadottegymnasiet", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, -170)
        pendown()
        write("D. Pauliskolan", font=quest, align='center')

        penup()
        setposition(0, 250)
        pendown()
        write("Vad är Malmös bästa skola?", font=main, align='center')

        onkeypress(good, 'c')
        onkeypress(bad, 'a')
        onkeypress(bad, 'd')
        onkeypress(bad, 'b')
        listen()








    onscreenclick(reset)


onscreenclick(reset)
done()
```

Sorry if my code seems sloppy, or anything similar, but I just need help with how to make a question not appear again after it appeared once.
And I know turtle might not be the best, but it's the only thing I could think of when doing this simple project.
Thanks for any help I get, it means alot!

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that each time you call reset() you want a non-repeated element from the frågor list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this line of code:

```
frågor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

...and put it outside of the reset() function - i.e., into global space

Then...

```
computer_action = random.choice(frågor)
frågor.remove(computer_action)
```

In other words, you make a random selection from the list then you remove whatever you selected.

The problem is that you'll only be able to do this *len(frågor)* times. You'll need to figure out how to cope with that eventuality

Comment: Worked like a charm for what I needed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you have to say that `computer_action=0` if you want to end or change the 0 with another number like 3 to continue with your questions

if computer_action == 1:

```
penup()
setposition(0, 130)
pendown()
write("A. Danmark", font=quest, align='center')

penup()
setposition(0, 30)
pendown()
write("B. Sverige", font=quest, align='center')

penup()
setposition(0, -70)
pendown()
write("C. Finland", font=quest, align='center')

penup()
setposition(0, -170)
pendown()
write("D. Norge", font=quest, align='center')

penup()
setposition(0, 250)
pendown()
write("Vad heter det största landet i Norden?", font=main, align='center')

onkeypress(good, 'b')
onkeypress(bad, 'd')
onkeypress(bad, 'c')
onkeypress(bad, 'a')
listen()
computer_action=0
```

I am not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Define your intial `frågor` outside of your `reset`-function. Then modify your `computer-action` like the following:

```
frågor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def reset(x, y):
    #.... 
    random.shuffle(frågor)
    computer_action = frågor.pop()
```

`pop` returns the last element of the list `frågor` and deletes it from the list. So it can't ever be repeated.

Minor hint: avoid special characters like å in variables. Might result in problems when the encoding of your file changes.